# Why does AngularJS not use instanceof in its isArray function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

From AngularJS `isArray` source:

```
return toString.call(value) === '[object Array]';
```

Why did they not go with?

```
return value instanceof Array;
```

Answer (score 8):

Because if you receive an array from a different `window` (e.g., another frame or iframe, a child window, a parent window, etc.), it won't be `instanceof` the `Array` constructor in *your* window.

This is why in ES5 they added the [`Array.isArray` function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.3.2) to JavaScript, so we could stop doing it the hard way, which looks like this:

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(theArray) === "[object Array]") ...
```

Example of the various aspects of this: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/vejot/1)

Parent window:

```
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Click To Open Window">
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var wnd;

    document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
      wnd = window.open("http://jsbin.com/yimug/1");
      display("Opened, waiting for child window to load...");
      setTimeout(waitForChild, 10);
    };

    function waitForChild() {
      if (wnd && wnd.sendMeSomething) {
        display("Child window loaded, sending [1, 2, 3]");
        wnd.sendMeSomething([1, 2, 3]);
      }
    }

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
```

Child window:

```
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    window.sendMeSomething = function(something) {
      display("Got " + something.join(", "));
      display("something instanceof Array? " + (something instanceof Array));
      display("Object.prototype.toString.call(something): " + Object.prototype.toString.call(something));
      if (Array.isArray) {
        display("Array.isArray(something)? " + Array.isArray(something));
      }
    };
    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
```

Output (in child window) *(`something` is the name of the argument where it receives an array from the parent)*:

```
Got 1, 2, 3
something instanceof Array? false
Object.prototype.toString.call(something): [object Array]
Array.isArray(something)? true
```

Comment: How did you learn that? Is there a book that discusses these "minutiae".

Comment: @Ben: LOL Excellent question. Years of kicking around JavaScript, discussion groups, running into issues like this myself, reading and answering things on SO, and delving into the deep inner workings of JavaScript... I haven't found a book that covers these sorts of oddities *specifically*, but a decent in-depth book should cover many of them.

Comment: @Ben: My pleasure, hope that helped. :-)